# System and Users Messages Structure

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating an app where there are a users table and an admin table. In this app one of the features I'm building is a messaging, where users receive some kind of messages, and then the users are notified.

I'm struggling with my database architecture and note sure if this is the best approach. In my table messages I have another table that is the `messages_translations` and also `user_messages`.

My goal is to have it scalable and also be the best practice in doing.

At first I have my table messages like this:

```
messages:
- id;
- user_id (to);
- admin_id (from);
- title;
- body;
- is_read;
```

But than I remember 2 things: first I forgot to make in multilanguage and also I need a way to say that this message is from the admin to the users or from the system.
For example, there are situations that messages that are notified from the system (ex: a candidate was accepted or not, a new opening job available, or some kinda a approval), basically events from the system related with the users., and other times are messages from the admin to the users or group of users with a more specific message.

And one of the reasons i created `users_messages` is to prevent duplication of content, because there will be situations the Admin will need to send the same message to a group of users based on gender, or other detail.

So this is the last approach I did:

```
messages:
- id;
- type (SYSTEM, ADMIN)

messages_translated:
- id;
- message_id;
- locale (en, es...);
- title;
- body;

user_messages:
- id;
- message_id;
- user_id;
- admin_id (nullable);
- is_read;
```

So basically what I did, does this structure makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do with one less table:

```
table "message":
- id;
- creation_date_time;
- language (ENG, SPA... ISO 639-2);
- title;
- body;

table "message_sent":
- id;
- message_id;
- sent_date_time;
- receiver_user_id;
- sender_admin_id (if null then it is a system message);
- is_read;
```

So, because the content will be the same for many receivers and should be translated I do place the content in a separate table.

The other table is for the messages that have been sent. I don't use a `TYPE` because system messages can simply have no sender, or a sender ID of -1.

In most cases it is best to use [ISO 639-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) for the language. Other codes will do, but this one is used the most, so if you start interacting with other libraries this is probably the one that you will encounter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the only thing that is kind strange for me is the System messages, for example i need in the activuity of the user in is control panel show the message notifications with the custom messages received from the Administrations but also with messages that are pre-build in the system (ex: event observers with custome routines messages) and i feel that im filling the table messages with repeat information, of course that is different users that are sent, but the messages of the system are the same for all.

Comment: There's not much repetition in the `"message_sent"` table for system messages. Only the `sender_admin_id` and the `message_id` are the same. I also noticed that you forgot a timestamp of when the message was sent, I'll add it in my answer.

Comment: But for example for the table "message" could have.

Comment: You message table is not well structure, you need to have a parent message and then have another table that is the translated content related with the message, the way you did there are no wayhave one message that is the same with differnt languages.

Comment: In my experience it not needed to know that messages in different languages are actually the same message. Often messages are not send in all languages, or slightly different in different languages anyway. But if you need that feature than your third table is indeed needed.